# How to view last completed research?

Tags: factorio

Is there a way to get the latest research that was completed or have the game write a message with the research name?
I always put tons of research into the queue and focus on some other task.
When the research completes I'm suprised and wonder what I was planning with the just completed research.
Without research queue it's even worse, because what research should be queued next for the larger plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's a [mod](https://mods.factorio.com/mod/DeadlockResearchNotifications) for this.
It even shows the icon for that research!